# Typescript definition file (.d.ts) for a JS lib that uses fluent/chaining API

Tags: typescript

I am writing a definition file for a JS lib that uses method chaining. But in a slightly more complex way than what I had seen before because it also uses/reuses abstract base classes. So I came down with this approach:

```
// the test.d.ts
    declare module someJSChainingLib {

  export interface IbaseA <T>{
    function1: () => T;
  }
  export interface IbaseB<T> {
    function2: () => T;
  }

  export interface IbaseC<T> {
    function3: () => T;
  }

  export interface IbaseD<T> {
    function4: () => T;
  }

  export interface ICombinator1 extends IbaseA<ICombinator1>, IbaseB<ICombinator1>, IbaseC<ICombinator1> {
  // possibly add more stuff here 
  }

  export interface ICombinator2 extends IbaseA<ICombinator2>, IbaseB<ICombinator2>, IbaseD<ICombinator2> {
  // possibly add more stuff here
  }


  export interface IFeature1 extends ICombinator1 {
  // this has the base interfaces A,B,C
  // possibly add more stuff here
  }


  export interface IFeature2 extends ICombinator2 {
  // this has the base interfaces A,B,D     
  // possibly add more stuff here
  }

}
```

on the consuming side it looks like this :

```
///<reference path="test.d.ts" />

function callit() {

  var test1: someJSChainingLib.IFeature1;
  test1.function1().function2().function3();  


  var test2: someJSChainingLib.IFeature2;
  test2.function1().function2().function4();
}
```

The features re-use some of the base interfaces and mix them as needed. I am wondering if there is a better way of typing this? or if the generics are the way to go?

Comment: I don't think generics is relevant here, unless your different "functions" are actually the same implementation with different types.

Comment: You way is the "official" way of simulating mixin support with TypeScript (until it has true mixin syntax that is), so I think it looks fine.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the answer! yes that is what they are, the implementation is identical for all different types of features. So in the context of feature1 the returned instance is of type feature1 and in the context of feature2 they return instances of type feature2.

Comment: It feels that you are doing something wrong here. Why would you want to combine functions into interfaceA and also into interfaceB?
What is the logic that you are trying to build here? maybe you can build the structure accordingly.

Comment: @gilamran : this is a common pattern in js called mixin, different "objects" share functions, dc.js (https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js) is a good example for this technique, I was only writing the typescript definition to describe the behavior.

Comment: If you are looking for mixin? Go with: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#mixins

Comment: ...I was just writing the d.ts file for a library that uses mixins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen Chungs comment:

> I don't think generics is relevant here, unless your different
>   "functions" are actually the same implementation with different types.
>   You way is the "official" way of simulating mixin support with
>   TypeScript (until it has true mixin syntax that is), so I think it
>   looks fine.

is the answer, so I am "answering" here in order for the question to not show up as unanswered anymore.